# как в phpunit через метод call() отправить заголовки?

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit

Передаю через call() файл, как передать заголовки?

```
 $file = new UploadedFile(public_path('tests\images\test.png'), 'test.png', null, 'image/png', null, true);
 $filename = $this->call('POST', '/api/admin/upload', [], [], ['file' => $file], ['Accept' => 'application/json']);
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Попробуй так

```
$server = $this->transformHeadersToServerVars($headers);
```

Где $headers это ассоциативный массив твоих заголовков, и вставь последним параметров в функции call

```
$this->call($method, $uri, $params, $cookie, $files, $server);
```